# Django SMTP Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

Tags: python, django, email

I set up django email backend following way:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Host for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_HOST = 'mytdl.de'

# Port for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_PORT = 25

# Optional SMTP authentication information for EMAIL_HOST.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@mytdl.de'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

But sending emails with django-allauth will return following error:

```
(535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')
```

Testing the the settings with

```
 telnet  mytdl.de 25
```

or Thunderbird as email client works fine.

```
2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

But Django / SMTP stills throws that error.
Django also tries to

```
AUTH CRAM-MD5
```

and not

```
AUTH LOGIN
```

any ideas?

Comment: you sure the password is being passed to the settings file properly, try once by putting the password in the settings file and then try to send mail

Comment: Try sending emails from the shell first.

Answer (score 2):

If your email host is gmail then you can fix it with these simple steps:

1. Login to your **gmail account** (The one you are using in your Django application for sending mails ).
2. Then select **Account** from google apps or click [here](https://myaccount.google.com/).
3. On your control panel click on **Apps with account access** under Sign-in & security.
4. Then scroll down and enable **Allow less secure apps**

Also maintain your settings variables in this order:

***settings.py***

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```